# Google Visualization and Plone - "e[0].K is undefined" error message

Tags: plone, google-visualization

I just posted this in the [Google Visualization group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-visualization-api/epKbvkRi9qs), but I thought I would reach out to the Plone community as well for help.

I am using Plone 4.2.4 and wanted to integrate Google Charts with an Oracle back end via cx_Oracle.  There is already a very nice package called [EEA.Daviz](https://github.com/collective/eea.daviz).  However, it was way more than I needed and I thought I could do it on my own, so I created some page templates and Python code that wraps the Javascript.  On my laptop (Mac OS X) it all worked fine.

However, once I pushed it to my server (SLES 10), BarCharts stopped working.  I have only tested Bar, Line and Motion charts.  All I get is a red error box that says "e[0].K is undefined".  After googling around, I found [a very similar description](http://www.sebdangerfield.me.uk/2010/08/b0-is-undefined-error-when-using-googles-visualization-api/) of my problem that suggests it is a Google Visualization error and the fix is to change the width and height properties.  However, changing the height or width did not fix it.  What is very strange is that, if I copy the example JS from the BarChart page and copy it into a vanilla Zope Page Template, it works just fine.  However, once I wrap it in the master template, I get the red error message again.

So I am confused.  I have the same theme installed on my laptop and it did not give me any problems.  I know I can display BarCharts on the server without the theme in a vanilla Page Template.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

ZPT that Works:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                                function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['COUNTRY', ' COUNT'],
['Austria', 19],
['Belgium', 73],
['Bulgaria', 20]]
                  ); var options = {
                     title: 'Test Bar Chart'}; var chart = new  google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                  chart.draw(data, options);}
</script>
</head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 1000px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

ZPT that does NOT work:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
          xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
          xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
          xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
          lang="en"
          metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
          i18n:domain="plone">

    <metal:main fill-slot="javascript_head_slot">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                                    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                                    function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['COUNTRY', ' COUNT'],
    ['Austria', 19],
    ['Belgium', 73],
    ['Bulgaria', 20]]
                      ); var options = {
                         title: 'Test Bar Chart'}; var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                      chart.draw(data, options);}
    </script>
    </metal:main>

  <body>
<metal:main fill-slot="main">
<tal:main-macro metal:define-macro="main">

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 1000px;"></div>

</tal:main-macro>
</metal:main>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've discovered that for some reason disabling kupuhelpers.js causes the error to go away.  And I realized on my laptop instance I have TinyMCE installed and not Kupu.  Very strange!  Any ideas why kupuhelpers.js would block it?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your second example and it seems to work as intended so maybe there is something wrong with your data coming from Oracle (format, missing values, etc). You'll have to do some JS debugging out there. Try adding a breakpoint to see what **e[0]** is and why it doesn't have the **K** attribute (or why **e** is an empty Array).

Also, [EEA Daviz](http://eea.github.io/docs/eea.daviz/) is a bundle that brings together multiple Visualization frameworks ([Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart), [Simile Exhibit](http://www.simile-widgets.org/exhibit3/) and in the near future [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)) but you can always use one or more of its components without bringing in the entire *plane* Thus, you should also try [EEA Google Charts](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/eea.googlecharts). Don't forget that you'll need [collective.js.jqueryui](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.js.jqueryui) **< 1.9** for Plone 4.2.x

[image: Testing in Plone]

Comment: Yes, I've tested EEA.Daviz.  I'm a bit unsure how to pass row data to EEA Google Charts programmatically.  I have created a test with CSV data, but I will either want to set that field or send Google Charts the row data on the fly from Oracle.  Any tips?

Comment: Also, see my comment above.  For some reason disabling kupuhelpers.js makes the error go away.  I have no idea why or how it is related, but it works.